# resize height of textarea with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am try to duplicate fb like comment box , where they resize as text fills it using [Expanding Text Areas Made Elegant](http://alistapart.com/article/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant)

My view looks like:

```
<div class='expandingArea'>
    <pre><span></span></pre>
    <textarea id="comment_body" name="comment[body]" placeholder="In my opinion...">
    </textarea>
</div>
<input class="comment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Comment" />
```

my jquery is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('div.expandingArea').each(function() {
    var area = $('textarea', $(this));
    var span = $('span', $(this));
    area.bind('input', function() {
      span.text(area.val());
      $(".comment_submit").css({"margin": "0.25em 0"});
      $(".expandingArea.active textarea").css({"padding": "5px", "height": "95%"});
    });
    span.text(area.val());
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

As user fills in data, the text area height increases and everything is fine. Then to submit he clicks on `submit` button, which makes an ajax call, entered data gets stored in database and I reset the content of text area with:

```
$('textarea').val('');
```

But I need to set the height of text area back to it's origin height(When user enter text, its height was increased as text filled it). I can't use something like:

```
$('textarea').height(10);
```

As that will add `height = 10px` to element style of textarea and then my resizing of textarea when user enters data in textarea won't work.Does anyone know how can I undo that resizing of textarea?

Further, if user types something in textarea after submitting then textarea resizes to normal size on it's own. I guess that triggers `input` binded with textarea. So faking user input sort of thing can also work, but I don't know how to do it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind the function that does the resizing on the `input` event. When you empty the textarea it updates the value, but the event isn't triggered yet. One way to force the event is:

```
$('textarea').val('').trigger('input');
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5epsubs/1/)

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I wanted to know this very thing.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('div.expandingArea').each(function() {
    var area = $('textarea', $(this));
    var span = $('span', $(this));
    area.bind('input', function() {
      span.text(area.val());
      area.attr('rows', 10);  
    });
    span.text(area.val());
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('.comment_submit').click(function() {        
     $('#comment_body').attr('rows', 2).val('');
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ronqt8mc/

Comment: Sorry, Adriano. It just adds `row = 10` to textarea and has no other effect ie size of textarea remains the same.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#comment_body").css("height", "50px"); // 50px - your default size.
```

Thanks Adriano Godoy

Comment: This is the same as `$('textarea').height(50);` which is hardly any different from `$('textarea').height(10);` that OP is trying.

Comment: @Popnoodles I didn't read or test the method of the asked person. Just started from the accepted answer and that won't work for me. Read second answer and its comments. Tried that idea in a simple form and it works for me. Your code is also works fine for me.